# How to use WSL2 miniconda environment's Python in PowerBI

Tags: python

If this does not belong here please feel free to delete this.

Right now when I go to Options in PowerBI and try to set the home directory for Python to the Python in the bin folder of one of my conda envs on WSL2 miniconda3, it won't even open the bin folder.
So I tried designating the bin folder but I get
"That isn't a valid Python home directory path.  Try browsing to a folder where Python is installed.